# How to write '\n' from keyboard with scanf() in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm **new to C** and I would like to know if it's possible to write into a string the character `\n` from **the keyboard** by using `scanf()` function.

The code that I'm using is this: (sorry for the Italian variables words)

```
void riempi_array_stringhe (char* stringhe[], int lunghezza_array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lunghezza_array; i++) {
        stringhe[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        printf("Insert a new string: ");
        scanf("%s", stringhe[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried type shift + enter, alt + enter, or to insert \n as input but not works at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doubt it can be done, just use getchar() or getch()

Comment: A little trick is save the string in a file and input it. e.g. python -c 'print "A\nB\nhi"' > foo and ./your program < foo

Comment: ...or even `fgets`

Comment: scanf is an input function: not an output function.  You can't write with an input function.

Comment: just press enter

Comment: This question has a curiosity purpose, so yes, I can even do it like you guys said (that is actually the best way because scanf is dangerous to use), but i was interested in doing this with scanf function.

Comment: @cup didn't exactly understand what you mean with this

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh if I just press enter I just say to the program that I finished to input the string.

Comment: what happens when you put '\n' as input in console, is there any error or any kind of output you are able to see

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh it just write \n in the string

Comment: Why do people insist on using `scanf` for everything under the sun? It's not always the best tool, and in fact is often the worst possible tool due to how it can and will wildly overfill buffers.

Comment: @tadman As I said in a comment before, This question has a curiosity purpose. You're right! scanf is the worst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `[` specifier. Quote from `scanf(2)`

> `[` — Matches a nonempty sequence  of  characters  from  the specified  set  of accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a terminating  null byte.

Example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        str[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        printf("Insert a new string: ");
        scanf("%[^~]", str[i]);
        printf("Your input: %s\n", str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To end the input we should input `~` and then `Enter` or press `Ctrl+D` (EOF). We can specify other characters to terminate the input. For example, `scanf("%[^X]", str[i]);` will terminate the input after user inserts an `X` and then `Enter`.

Please note, to prevent your buffer overrun, you should always specify the `width` of the sequence equals to the buffer size minus one (for `NUL` character), i.e.:

```
scanf("%99[^~]", str[i]); // read no more than 99 symbols + NUL
```

Comment: So the best way is to terminate the string input in a different way, and there is no char (or combination of chars) that can be inserted from keyboard that represent \n in an input right??

Comment: @LorenzoImperatrice user can input `\n` and we can manually substitute it to newline in our code, i.e.: `scanf(..., str[i]); str_replace(str[i], "\\n", "\n");` Please note there is no `strreplace()` in C, so you should google for an example implementation...

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Note that the `%[^EOF]` scan set looks for any character except capital-E, capital-O, capital-F — it has nothing to do with `EOF` except the coincidence that the list of letters is the same.  Also note that `%[^EOF]` will read newlines into the string; indeed, it will keep reading until it crashes, or encounters one of the letters, E, F, O, or it runs into EOF.  It won't stop merely because you reach the end of a line.